# Symbolic entropy maximization in SymPy

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, python

My goal is to use [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to solve certain problems of entropy maximization that are common in Physics in the field of statistical mechanics. Hence, I will:

- Introduce one of the simplest versions of such problems.
- Show my attempt to solve it in SymPy.
- Criticize such attempt and ask my question, accordingly.

The simple entropy maximization problem I have mentioned is formulated as follows. We would like to maximize the entropy

$H = - \sum_x P_x \ln P_x$

subject to the following constraints: *i)* the normalization constraint

$1 = \sum_x P_x$

and *ii)* the constraint of average energy

$U = \sum_i E_x P_x$

Here the index $i$ runs over $x=1,2,...,n$. $E_x$ represents the energy of the system when it is in microscopic state $x$ and $P_x$ is the probability for  microscopic state x to occur in the thermodynamic state of the system.

The solution to such a problem can be obtained by the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). In this context, it works as follows.

Firstly, the following Lagrangian is defined

$L = H + a( 1 - \sum_i P_x ) + b( U - \sum_i P_x E_x )$

Here, $a$ and $b$ are the Lagrange multipliers. The Lagrangian $L$ is a function of $a$, $b$ and the probabilities $P_x$ for $x=1,2,...,n$. The term $a( 1 - \sum_x P_x )$ correspond to the normalization constraint and the term $b( E - \sum_x P_x E_x )$ to the energy constraint.

Secondly, the partial derivatives of $L$ with respect to $a$, $b$ and the $P_x$ for the different $x=1,2,...,n$ are calculated. These result in

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = 1 - \sum_x P_x$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial b} = E - \sum_x E_x P_x$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial P_x} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial P_x} - a - b E_x = - \ln P_x - 1 - a - b E_x$

Thirdly, we find the solution to the entropy maximization problem by equating these derivatives to zero. This makes sense since there are $2+n$ equations and we have $2+n$ unknowns: $a$, $b$ and the $P_x$. The solution from these equations reads

$P_x = \frac{\exp( - b E_x )}{Z}$

where

$Z = \sum_x \exp( - b E_x )$

is called the partition function and $b$ is implicitly determined by the equation

$E = \sum_x P_x E_x = \frac{1}{Z} \sum_x \exp( -b E_x ) E_x$

This completes the "hand-made" construction of the solution of the problem of entropy maximization.

Now, lets try to "imitate" such construction using SymPy. The idea is to automatize the process so, eventually, I can attack similar but more complicate problems just by "crunching" with the code. The following is my attempt up to now:

```
# Lets attempt to derive these analytical result using SymPy.

>>> import sympy as sy
>>> import sympy.tensor as syt

>>> # Here, n is introduced to specify an abstract range for x and y.
>>> n = sy.symbols( 'n' , integer = True )
>>> a , b = sy.symbols( 'a b' ) # The Lagrange-multipliers.
>>> x = syt.Idx( 'x' , n ) # Index x for P_x
>>> y = syt.Idx( 'y' , n ) # Index y for P_y; this is required to take derivatives according to SymPy rules.

>>> P = syt.IndexedBase( 'P' ) # The unknowns P_x.
>>> E = syt.IndexedBase( 'E' ) # The knowns E_x; each being the energy of state x.
>>> U = sy.Symbol( 'U' ) # Mean energy.
>>> 
>>> # Entropy
>>> H = sy.Sum( - P[x] * sy.log( P[x] ) , x )
>>> 
>>> # Lagrangian
>>> L = H + a * ( 1 - sy.Sum( P[x] , x ) ) + b * ( U - sy.Sum( E[x] * P[x] , x ) )

>>> # Lets compute the derivatives
>>> dLda = sy.diff( L , a )
>>> dLdb = sy.diff( L , b )
>>> dLdPy = sy.diff( L , P[y] )

>>> # These look like
>>> 
>>> print dLda
-Sum(P[x], (x, 0, n - 1)) + 1
>>> 
>>> print dLdb
U - Sum(E[x]*P[x], (x, 0, n - 1))
>>>  
>>> print dLdPy
-a*Sum(KroneckerDelta(x, y), (x, 0, n - 1)) - b*Sum(KroneckerDelta(x, y)*E[x], (x, 0, n - 1)) + Sum(-log(P[x])*KroneckerDelta(x, y) - KroneckerDelta(x, y), (x, 0, n - 1))

>>> # The following approach does not work
>>> 
>>> tmp = dLdPy.doit()
>>> print tmp
-a*Piecewise((1, 0 <= y), (0, True)) - b*Piecewise((E[y], 0 <= y), (0, True)) + Piecewise((-log(P[y]) - 1, 0 <= y), (0, True))
>>>     
>>> sy.solve( tmp , P[y] )
[]
>>> # As we can see, no solution was found for P[y]

>>> # Hence, we try an ad-hoc procedure
>>> Px = sy.Symbol( 'Px' )
>>> Ex = sy.Symbol( 'Ex' )
>>> tmp2 = dLdPy.doit().subs( P[y] , Px ).subs( E[y] , Ex ).subs( y , 0 )
>>> print tmp2
-Ex*b - a - log(Px) - 1
>>> Px = sy.solve( tmp2 , Px )
>>> print Px
[exp(-Ex*b - a - 1)]
>>> # This is the solution we wanted to find. After asking for normalization the constant "a" can be absorbed into 1/Z.
```

My critics and questions are the following:

- I do not like the idea of using the "had-hoc" procedure. Why `solve` is not able to find the solution for `P[y]`?
- Is there another more "correct" or preferable way to do this?.

Comment: According to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065328/symbolic-entropy-maximization-in-sympy), there is a bug in the current version of SymPy reason for which the derivative with respect to `P[y]` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `solveset` instead of `solve` you get a solution.

Check the following snippet.

```
import sympy as sy
import sympy.tensor as syt

# Here, n is introduced to specify an abstract range for x and y.
n = sy.symbols('n', integer=True)
a , b = sy.symbols( 'a b' ) # The Lagrange-multipliers.
x = syt.Idx('x', n) # Index x for P_x
y = syt.Idx('y', n) # Index y for P_y; this is required to take
                       # derivatives according to SymPy rules.
P = syt.IndexedBase('P') # The unknowns P_x.
E = syt.IndexedBase('E') # The knowns E_x; each being the energy of state x.
U = sy.Symbol('U') # Mean energy.

# Entropy
H = sy.Sum(-P[x] * sy.log(P[x]), x)

# Lagrangian
L = H + a * (1 - sy.Sum(P[x], x)) + b * (U - sy.Sum(E[x] * P[x], x))

dLda = sy.diff(L, a)
dLdb = sy.diff(L, b)
dLdPy = sy.diff(L, P[y])
tmp = dLdPy.doit()
sol = sy.solveset(tmp, P[y])
```

That gives as answer

$$e^{- a - b E_{y} - 1}\, .$$